# Reactivemongo nested JSON structure

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm currently working on simple project in `Play Framework 2.3.6` with reactivemongo `"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"` and I have problem with nested structure.

My goal is to map such as JSON structure (to Scala equivalent):

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    url: String,
    description: String,
    visitors: [
        _id: ObjectId,
        isFirstTime: Boolean
    ]
}
```

My Scala code:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.BSONFormats._
import reactivemongo.bson._
import reactivemongo.bson.BSONObjectID

case class Visitor(_id: BSONObjectID, isFirstTime: Boolean)
case class Project(_id: BSONObjectID, url: String, description: String, visitors: List[Visitor])

object JSONFormats {
    implicit val projectFormat = Json.format[Project]
}
```

In the last line the following error appears : `"No implicit format for List[models.Visitor] available."`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a formatter for `Visitor`.  Idiomatically, these should go in the companion objects.

```
object Visitor {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[Visitor]
}

object Project {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[Project]
}
```